# Transforming region y-x>0 to the upper half plane through change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation

I am dealing with the region $y-x>0$. I would like to transform this region by rotating it to end up with the upper half plane.

So far I have tried to create the new region by taking $\tilde{y}=y-x$. Then the transformed region would be $\tilde{y} >0$ which is what I want. However, I'm confused on how to deal with the $\tilde{x}$ in this new transformed space. All I know so far about this coordinate is that $\tilde{x}=y-x=0$ and that it is essentially just the original $x$ axis rotated by 45 degrees. I am looking for help explicitly defining $\tilde{x}$. If there is something obvious I am missing please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: You initially have that $y$-tilda is $y-x$ and later you say that $x$-tilda is also $y-x$ [and is also $0$ since you have it expressed as $y-x=0.$ This is confusing.

Comment: @coffeemath what do you mean by that?

Comment: I corrected my comment.

Comment: @coffeemath Okay I see it now thanks! It was a bit confusing how I wrote it out. Basically, I want to take $\tilde{y}$ to be y-x. I was just writing out any information I knew about $\tilde{x}$ I'm really not sure how to go from there and further define it. I was trying to express that the $\tilde{x}$ axis in the new coordinate system is given by the line $y-x=0$ in the original coordinate system.

Comment: One way to do what you want is to use a rotation matrix. Because when rotated by 45 degrees *clockwise* the region above $y=x$ winds up as the region above the $x$ axis.

Comment: @coffeemath interesting concept can you please explain a little more how I can go about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119720/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-k12345).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make computations simpler the point $(x,y)$ in the plane before transforming can be sent to the point $(u,v)=(y+x,y-x).$ This is in fact the result of rotating by $-\pi/4$ but then stretching by a factor of $\sqrt{2}.$

Then if originally $y-x>0$ then the altered second coordinate $v$ is greater than $0$ as desired. The fact that the new first coordinate is $y+x$ might make one think it must be positive, but if one finds the inverse of our map it is $(x,y)=((u-v)/2,(u+v)/2.)$ So for example the point $(x,y)=(-2,-1)$ maps to the point $(u,v)=(-3,1)$ showing a case where the new first coordinate is negative.

To explain how I got my $(u,v)$ : First I used complex numbers to do a rotation through $-\pi/4$ using the fact that angles add when complex numbers multiply, so that multiplying $x+i y$ by $e^{-i \pi/4}$ gives the complex number $(u,v)=(y+x)/\sqrt{2}+i(y-x)/\sqrt{2}.$ [to do this i wrote $e^{i (-\pi/4)}$ in the form $1/\sqrt{2}-i(1/\sqrt{2}).$]

Then thinking the squareroot of two made it complicated I just dropped it, hence the stretch by that factor.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the type of answer I wanted to get. Can you explain a little further how you got u= y+x please?

Comment: @k12345 Just added an explanation at the end. I used complex number multiplication.

Comment: @coffemath Thank you so much ! This helped a lot.